# Where can I find the unit tests for Google's iosched 2012 app?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I can't find any unit tests in its [public repo](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/) .

Can anyone help me find the missing unit tests? Or recommend another open source Android app with decent unit test coverage?

I'm trying to find one to learn about how to unit test a real app.

Comment: CTS has 1000's of tests: http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html